unable to unpickle a file on windows that was pickle on MAC
I'm trying to unpickle a file called nlp.pk, it was pickled on a MAC and now I'm trying to unpickle it on windows.
below is the piece of code I'm using to unpickle the file
_dependency_file_path = {
    "VECTORIZER" : "./vectorizer.pk",
    "VECTORS" : "./vectors.pk",
    "LINKS" : "./links.pk",
    "NORMALIZER" : "./normalizer.pk",
    "NLP" : "./nlp.pk"
}

def dependency_loader():
    dependencies = {}

    DEFAULT_PICKLE_FILEPATH_TYPE = pathlib.PosixPath
    if platform.system()=="Windows":
        pathlib.PosixPath = pathlib.WindowsPath

    for filename,filepath in _dependency_file_path.items():
        try:
            with open(filepath, "rb") as file:
                dependencies[filename] = pickle.load(file)
                print(f"{filename} loaded!")
        except Exception as E:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Exception:{E}")
        
    pathlib.PosixPath = DEFAULT_PICKLE_FILEPATH_TYPE
    return dependencies

It doesn't show any error or warning, just straight up crashes, I tried running it on jupyter notebook (in anaconda env) but it keep crashing the kernel and doesn't give any error. I tried running the notebook on vscode but was followed by an error that has been briefed in this thread: kernel process dies because of deprecated support for extra string quotes in traitlets 5
Here's the output, the other 4 files unpickle just fine, the only problem is with nlp.pk. Although the other 4 file didn't even require to change PosixPath, they unpickled directly. the nlp.pk produced the PosixPath error the first time but after working around it (as shown in above code), this crashing thing started happening

Please create a minimal reproducible example. In my attempt, with your approach, it did not crash and was able to unpickle correctly.

I have provided the minimal reproducible example. as for the .pk files, may be try running mine: project. just to confirm: I'm facing issue on Windows on Mac it is working fine. The snippet can be found in dependency.py

So many questions here... Which Python version are you using? When pickling and when unpickling. What is the minimal pickled content needed to cause the problem? Why are you modifying pathlib.PosixPath? Why are you even using pickle for this?

So, are you saying that we need a 16MB file to reproduce the issue? If so, it doesn't sound like a PosixPath issue. If not, it's not a minimal example. Creating an MRE is not only a good way to ask a question, but it also helps you identify the exact cause of the issue. My current guess is that your PosixPath patch is working fine, but something after that is causing the issue.

the main issue here is unpickling the mentioned file so yes you'd need that file in order to reproduce it. it was originally pickled on a MAC and is required tobe unpickled on windows. As mentioned in the last para, It created PosixPath issue at first but after the patch, it just started crashing without any errors so yes it can be assumed that atleast the patch is working fine (not guaranteed though) and the issue is something else. as for the Minimal example, I've literally mentioned just the method creating the issue, what can I minimize more in this?

to reproduce it, create a .py file, paste above snippet and call the dependency_loader() at the end. download the nlp.pk file from the repo and place it beside the .py file. you can download all the menthod file or just nlp.pk but make sure to change _dependency_file_path accordingly. run the .py file note: the problem is unpickling the nlp.pk file specifically, not unpickling any random pickled file. Also you'd need this libs for snippet to run platform pathlib pickle spacy

You misunderstand the concept of a minimal. If unpickling a 16MB file is the minimal, that means it won't crash when unpickling a 15MB file. To test this, you can unpickle it on Mac, split the object into two, pickle them back into separate files on Mac, unpickle them on Windows to find out which file (objects) is causing the error. Then repeat until you can narrow it down to a few objects, or a single object if you can. This is the divide-and-conquer method that the document suggests.

Also, FYI, as documented here, it is possible to construct malicious pickle data which will execute arbitrary code during unpickling. So please do not expect others to unpickle a 16MB file that is uploaded to the external site and only linked in the comment. Therefore, once you have successfully narrowed it down to a few objects, it may be better to also provide the code in your question that generates the pickle file to get more people involved.
